# Compare and Get Only Date Part of Datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am trying to compare two dates, today's date and another date saved in database as string.

When I convert them, I get the time part as `12:00:00`.

This is my code:

```
Datetime dt_today = Datetime.Now.ToShortDateString();
Datetime savedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(retrievedDate).ToShortDateString();

If (dt_Today == savedDate)
{ 
    // Do this
}
```

The two dates return time as `12:00:00` and the date I want is just to be in format of "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: If both `DateTime` values have the same time, then just compare them. You can't assign a string to a `DateTime` value

Comment: You can't assign a string to a datetime. If you really need only the date you can use `dt_today.Date` and `savedDate.Date`

Comment: Don't compare strings, compare datetime objects using the `Date` property

Comment: If the time component is already at 12:00:00, then your `DateTime` values are already equivalent to the `DateTime.Date` property of each.

Comment: Just compare the dates only: `If (dt_Today.Date == savedDate.Date)`

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, But i have used Convert.Todatetime to convert the string to date...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Days Property to check whether the date is same or not.

```
Datetime dt_today = Datetime.Now;
If ((dt_Today - retrievedDate).Days == 0 )
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One line will do this check:

```cs
if (retrievedDate.Date.Equals(DateTime.Today))
{
    // Do this.
}
```